# Tony Millions Reachability class incorrectly reports unreachable from iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ios-simulator, reachability

I am having consistent issues with the Reachability class reporting incorrect state and losing notifications from Tony Millions reachability class. Although something similar has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367351/tony-million-reachability-says-unreachable-when-connected/) I would like to add more information that may or may not be useful in resolving my variation of the problem.

Firstly, I'm using the latest Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105) and am working on a Macbook Pro connected via Wifi and have downloaded the latest Reachability class (as of today by post date 5 Aug 2015) which I have set up as an instance that I pass around my iPhone application (not a singleton pattern).

Secondly, and probably quite importantly I'm using the **iOS simulator** in order to get the application behaviour correct before deploying it to an iPhone.

I'm taking advantage of both the notification mechanism, and also the direct 'isReachable' method depending on my usage about the code - notifications for triggering sync'ing and status bar updates and the 'isReachable' for conditional method calls. The reachability class is instantiated in the app delegate using this style:

```
[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:hostAddress]
```

And the reachability notification service is started using the

```
[reachability startNotifier]
```

method. Now, when the application starts, the reachability correctly indicates network access (be that up or down) and I also receive notifications as expected.

If I simulate the network failing by turning of Wifi (Turn off wifi from the computers perspective) I correctly receive the notification that the network is no longer reachable. But when I turn Wifi back on again I receive another notification which also tells me that the network is no longer reachable - even though it is. In addition, the 'isReachable' method also reports incorrectly.

Note that I call isReachable immediately after the result of a notification from NSNotificationCentre. I also ask for isReachable calls on different threads (does this matter)? Occasionally I simply don't get reachability updates at all, and eventually the notifier just seems to stop working.

Any one have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!